# Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I need a form that would handle blank fields. To do this, I create an array of column names using a foreach loop to check if the particular POST variable is an empty string. However, the first item, well_no, is not input directly through the form, but is computed from 2 other POST variables

```
($well_no = $date_completed."-".substr($country,0,2)."-".mt_rand(1,9).mt_rand(10,50);)
```

Therefore, I initiate both column array and the values array with this first column name and value respectively.

Here is the code

```
$col = []; // array of columns
$input = []; // array of prepared query input values

// add the well no
$input[] = $well_no; 
$col = ["well_no"];
//print_r($col);
        
        // loop over the defining array
foreach($fields as $field)
{
    // note: empty considers 0 or '0' to be an empty value. this will prohibit a numerical zero value being used.
    //  instead test if the value is or is not an empty string.
    if($_POST[$field] !== '')
    {
        $col[] = "$field";
        $input[] = $_POST[$field];
    }
}
```

I echo out both the column and values arrays and build the query:

```
echo "<p><b> column array</b></p>";
echo '<pre>'; print_r($col); echo '</pre>';
echo "<p> <b>values array</b></p>";
echo '<pre>'; print_r($input); echo '</pre>';

$sql = "INSERT INTO well_parent (".implode(',',$col).") VALUES (".implode(',', $input).")";
            $stmnt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $user_data = [':well_no'=>$well_no, ':easting'=>$easting, ':northing'=>$northing, ':purpose'=>$purpose,  ':country'=>$country, 
            ':admin1'=>$admin1, ':admin2'=> $admin2, ':admin3'=>$admin3, ':settlement'=>$settlement, ':orig_wellno'=>$orig_wellno, 
            ':date_completed'=> $date_completed, ':coord_sys'=> $coord_sys, ':elev'=>$elev, ':status'=>$status];
            
            echo "<p> <b>user_data array passed to stmnt->execute</b></p>";
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($user_data); echo '</pre>';
                        
            echo $sql;
            

            $stmnt->execute($user_data);
```

all the arrays look good but I receive an error Error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :well_no

As I understand, this happens when there is a mismatch between column name and values, or when parameters have the same name. I don't see evidence for this in my output, so something too subtle for my eyes is happening behind the scenes.

All I tried was to stare at my output:

column array

```
Array
(
    [0] => well_no
    [1] => purpose
    [2] => country
    [3] => admin1
    [4] => admin2
    [5] => admin3
    [6] => settlement
    [7] => date_completed
    [8] => elev
    [9] => status
)
```

values array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-05-09-US-829
    [1] => production
    [2] => USA
    [3] => NY
    [4] => NYC
    [5] => Bronx
    [6] => Parkchester
    [7] => 2017-05-09
    [8] => 44
    [9] => 1
)
```

user_data array passed to stmnt->execute

```
Array
(
    [:well_no] => 2017-05-09-US-829
    [:easting] => 
    [:northing] => 
    [:purpose] => production
    [:country] => USA
    [:admin1] => NY
    [:admin2] => NYC
    [:admin3] => Bronx
    [:settlement] => Parkchester
    [:orig_wellno] => 
    [:date_completed] => 2017-05-09
    [:coord_sys] => 
    [:elev] => 44
    [:status] => 1
)
```

SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO well_parent (well_no,purpose,country,admin1,admin2,admin3,settlement,date_completed,elev,status) 
VALUES (2017-05-09-US-829,production,USA,NY,NYC,Bronx,Parkchester,2017-05-09,44,1)
```

Everything looks okay to me, but I get the Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :well_no

I don't know if it is only well_no (the computed variable, not passed by POST) or all of them, and well_no was just the first error encountered. I'm stumped.

Comment: To me it looks `Invalid parameter number: :well_no` is indicating that the code is looking for a numbered parameter not a named one. I'm guessing because you did not follw proper form for binding parameters as shown here [Execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and [Prepared](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Dangerous code, prone to SQL injection.

Comment: This is all kinds of messy. You're meant to prepare a statement with placeholders in it, not raw values